# Check if all elements from a list are present in another list with Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am looking for the easiest way to check if all elements from a list are present in another bigger list, in Ansible.

Example checking that `['pkg_mgr', 'python']` are both present in `ansible_facts`.

Answer (score 2):

```
when: "{{ ['pkg_mgr', 'python'] | difference(ansible_facts.keys()) | length == 0 }}"
```

> Q: *"I am far from being pleased regarding how ugly it looks. I would be more than happy to see cleaner solutions."*

A: An empty list evaluates to `False` in Ansible. It's not necessary to test the length of the list. Ansible condition `when` expands the expression by default. It's not necessary to close it in braces. The equivalent condition is

```
when: not ['pkg_mgr', 'python']|difference(ansible_facts.keys())
```

---

**Python3** returns a `dictionary view object` instead of a list for methods `dict.keys(), dict.values(), and dict.items()`. Add `list` filter to make the code portable. See [Dictionary Views](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_python_version.html#dictionary-views).

```
when: not ['pkg_mgr', 'python']|difference(ansible_facts.keys()|list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution that works but I am far from being pleased regarding how ugly it looks.

```
- when: "{{ ['pkg_mgr', 'python'] | difference(ansible_facts.keys()) | length == 0 }}"
  ...
```

I would be more than happy to see cleaner solutions.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `is subset`?

Test:

```
- name: "Check lists"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local 
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ['pkg_mgr', 'python'] is subset(ansible_facts.keys()) }}"
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ['pkg_mgr', 'python', 'foo'] is subset(ansible_facts.keys()) }}"
```

Output:

```
PLAY [Check lists] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": true
}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": false
}
```